# How to access configuration as a bean?

Tags: java, spring

It is said in (rather old) documentation, that [`@Configuration` classes themselves are instantiated and managed as individual Spring beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s02.html).

Is this still true for now in Spring 4.x?

If so, then how to obtain one of these beans? For example, with `getBean()` method?

Comment: What did you try? Nothing?

Comment: You should explain what you tried already

Comment: You can browse my other questions to explore what I tried and what is overall context. Here -- is just a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to use a class anotated with @Configuration?

You can inject using @Autowired on your beans.

You can also inject an ApplicationContext on your class and use getBean()

Comment: I want a class, because it is said, that configs "are instantiated and managed as individual Spring beans". Why shouldn't I want it, if it is a normal bean?

Comment: You use @Configuration when you want to create a custom bean, so the spring container can use this custom bean where is required.

Comment: Example: You create a class CustomConfig and use the Configuration annotation on it. This class will have some method that return a SuperDuperCustomBean and this method is anotated with Bean annotation.
You dont need to retrieve the CustomConfig to get access to SuperDuperCustomBean, you can inject it direct in your class.
This is why you dont need to access your CustomConfig class.

Comment: `CustomConfig` can have other methods, rather than `@Bean` annotated. This is why I can wish to access it as a bean -- to call these methods.